# SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I'm trying to join 3 tables in a view; here is the situation:

I have a table that contains information of students who are applying to live on this College Campus. I have another table that lists the Hall Preferences (3 of them) for each Student. But each of these preferences are merely an ID Number, and the ID Number has a corresponding Hall Name in a third table (did not design this database...).

Pretty much, I have `INNER JOIN` on the table with their preferences, and their information, the result is something like...

```
 John Doe | 923423 | Incoming Student | 005
```

Where `005` would be the `HallID`. So Now I want to match that `HallID` to a third table, where this table contains a `HallID` and `HallName`.

So pretty much, I want my result to be like...

```
 John Doe | 923423 | Incoming Student | Foley Hall <---(INSTEAD OF 005)
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT
  s.StudentID, s.FName, 
  s.LName, s.Gender, s.BirthDate, s.Email, 
  r.HallPref1, r.HallPref2, r.HallPref3
FROM
  dbo.StudentSignUp AS s 
  INNER JOIN RoomSignUp.dbo.Incoming_Applications_Current AS r 
    ON s.StudentID = r.StudentID 
  INNER JOIN HallData.dbo.Halls AS h 
    ON r.HallPref1 = h.HallID
```

Answer (score 560, accepted):

You can do the following (I guessed on table fields,etc)

```
SELECT s.studentname
    , s.studentid
    , s.studentdesc
    , h.hallname
FROM students s
INNER JOIN hallprefs hp
    on s.studentid = hp.studentid
INNER JOIN halls h
    on hp.hallid = h.hallid
```

Based on your request for multiple halls you could do it this way. You just join on your Hall table multiple times for each room pref id:

```
SELECT     s.StudentID
    , s.FName
    , s.LName
    , s.Gender
    , s.BirthDate
    , s.Email
    , r.HallPref1
    , h1.hallName as Pref1HallName
    , r.HallPref2 
    , h2.hallName as Pref2HallName
    , r.HallPref3
    , h3.hallName as Pref3HallName
FROM  dbo.StudentSignUp AS s 
INNER JOIN RoomSignUp.dbo.Incoming_Applications_Current AS r 
    ON s.StudentID = r.StudentID 
INNER JOIN HallData.dbo.Halls AS h1 
    ON r.HallPref1 = h1.HallID
INNER JOIN HallData.dbo.Halls AS h2
    ON r.HallPref2 = h2.HallID
INNER JOIN HallData.dbo.Halls AS h3
    ON r.HallPref3 = h3.HallID
```

Comment: This works with just one preference, but how would I want to edit this to make it work with 3 preferences? (one column for each preference)

Comment: @BobSanders just updated my answer, then if you don't want the HallPref number just drop those columns

Answer (score 62):

If you have 3 tables with the same `ID` to be joined, I think it would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
JOIN table3 c ON a.ID = c.ID
```

Just replace `*` with what you want to get from the tables.

Comment: I don't know why this question was suggested to me but finally i have found that somebody answered with the easierst and clearest solution.

Answer (score 48):

```
SELECT column_Name1,column_name2,......
  From tbl_name1,tbl_name2,tbl_name3
  where tbl_name1.column_name = tbl_name2.column_name 
  and tbl_name2.column_name = tbl_name3.column_name
```

Comment: This answer lacks reasonable explanation to show the OP how to achieve the original goals.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT table1.col,table2.col,table3.col 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN 
(table2 INNER JOIN table3 
ON table3.id=table2.id) 
ON table1.id(f-key)=table2.id
AND //add any additional filters HERE
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need a second inner join that links the `ID Number` that you have now to the `ID Number` of the third table. Afterwards, replace the `ID Number` by the `Hall Name` and voilá :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    PersonAddress a, 
    Person b,
    PersonAdmin c
WHERE a.addressid LIKE '97%' 
    AND b.lastname LIKE 'test%'
    AND b.genderid IS NOT NULL
    AND a.partyid = c.partyid 
    AND b.partyid = c.partyid;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is correct query for join 3 table with same id**

```
select a.empname,a.empsalary,b.workstatus,b.bonus,c.dateofbirth from employee a, Report b,birth c where a.empid=b.empid and a.empid=c.empid and b.empid='103';
```

employee first table.
report second table.
birth third table

Answer (score 2):

There have been plenty of responses but the overall lesson seems to be that you can use multiple JOINS in a where clause; also techonthenet.com (my boss recommended it to me, that's how I found it) has good SQL tutorials if you ever have another question and you just want to try and figure it out.

```
SELECT table1.column1
FROM table1
WHERE table1 > 0 (or whatever you want to specify)
INNER JOIN table1 
ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
A.P_NAME AS [INDIVIDUAL NAME],B.F_DETAIL AS [INDIVIDUAL FEATURE],C.PL_PLACE AS [INDIVIDUAL LOCATION]
FROM 
[dbo].[PEOPLE] A
INNER JOIN 
[dbo].[FEATURE] B ON A.P_FEATURE = B.F_ID
INNER JOIN 
[dbo].[PEOPLE_LOCATION] C ON A.P_LOCATION = C.PL_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will work for you

```
Select b.id as 'id', u.id as 'freelancer_id', u.name as 
'free_lancer_name', p.user_id as 'project_owner', b.price as 
'bid_price', b.number_of_days as 'days' from User u, Project p, Bid b 
where b.user_id = u.id and b.project_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select products.product_id, product_name, price, created_at, image_name, categories.category_id, category_name,brands.brand_id, brand_name 
FROM products INNER JOIN categories USING (category_id) INNER JOIN brands USING(brand_id)
```

Answer (score -5):

```
select empid,empname,managename,[Management ],cityname  
from employees inner join Managment  
on employees.manageid = Managment.ManageId     
inner join CITY on employees.Cityid=CITY.CityId


id name  managename  managment  cityname
----------------------------------------
1  islam   hamza       it        cairo
```