# How to check rows present in more than two tables with MySQL command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables, cdb, ct_int, d_b and d_s, in MySQL database and need to extract infromation from cdb and ct_int by matching b.int_name with d_b table and d_s table columns. That is, I want to fetch rows from cdb and ct_int where b.column1 matching with c.column1 or c.column2 or d.column1. Following is the query:

select a.n_id, a.study_name, b.int_name, b.int_type, c.d_name from cdb a, ct_int b, d_b c, d_s d where a.dis like '%hun%' && b.int_name=(c.b_n or c.d_name or d.sym) && a.n_id=b.n_id;

This query is getting executed but taking lot of time without result since yesterday.

Please help in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well depends on how you want to match the columns but there is already an answer  here [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)