# Java - Inner Join with 3 Table

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2007, inner-join

i doing some project using Java(netbeans sw) and link to Microsoft Access.

The problem occur when i need to inner join 3 tables together from Microsoft Access,

i have no problem to inner join 2 tables together

```
rsUpdate = 

stmtUpdate.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM A_User Inner Join A_PC ON A_USER.SN = A_PC.SN");
```

which i able to get the result. But not inner join with 3 tables

```
rsUpdate = 

stmtUpdate.executeQuery

("SELECT * FROM A_User Inner Join A_CPU ON A_USER.SN = A_CPU.SN , Inner Join A_Software ON A_CPU.SN = A_Software.SN")
```

For the SQL above I have 3 "A" table separately for `USER | CPU | Software|`

```
USER PK is SN | CPU FK is SN | Software PK is SN |
```

The Error I got `java.sql.SQLException:Characters found after end SQL statement`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

Comment: You don't need comma "," between two `INNER JOIN` statement.
`SELECT * 
FROM A_User 
Inner Join A_CPU ON A_USER.SN = A_CPU.SN  
Inner Join A_Software ON A_CPU.SN = A_Software.SN`

Comment: i tried without comma but it prompt out syntax error in query expression

Comment: @RafaEl u r suggesting i use 3 table with same primary keys ?

Answer (score 3):

```
rsUpdate = 

stmtUpdate.executeQuery

("SELECT * FROM A_User
Inner Join A_CPU ON A_USER.SN = A_CPU.SN
Inner Join A_Software ON A_CPU.SN = A_Software.SN");
```

no need for ',' here... try this above code

Comment: i tried b4 this code, but is not working. "Syntax Error(Missing operator) in query expression"

Answer (score 2):

For Ms Access, when you `JOIN` more than table, the syntax is different. It should be this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ((a_user 
         INNER JOIN a_cpu 
                 ON a_user.sn = a_cpu.sn) 
        INNER JOIN a_software 
                ON a_cpu.sn = a_software.sn)
```

Comment: so you means (SELECT * FROM (A_USER Inner Join A_CPU on A_User.SN = A_CPU.SN) Inner Join A_Software ON A_CPU.SN = A_Software.SN) ?

Comment: is that your typo Inner INNER join ?

Comment: @FookShen - Sorry see my edit. Ms Access has a different syntax when joining multiple tables. This should work fine. Please try it.

Comment: if i use Innner INNER JOIN it will prompt out Syntax error in JOIN Operation.

Comment: @FookShen So sooory, it is a typo indeed, didn't so that sorry, remove it.

Comment: but if i use Select * FROM(A_User Inner Join A_CPU on A_User.SN = A_CPU.SN) Inner Join A_Software ON A_CPU.SN = A_Software.SN) it will pop out "error in row", which is means the following code might correct just the input field to link Access is not organize yet

Comment: @FookShen - Try it first in the Access directly and ensure that it is working fine. It should work fine

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Sure, keep it up ;)

Answer (score 1):

There should be no comma after the first join

```
rsUpdate = 

stmtUpdate.executeQuery

("SELECT * FROM A_User Inner Join A_CPU ON A_USER.SN = A_CPU.SN  Inner Join A_Software ON A_CPU.SN = A_Software.SN")
```

Comment: i tried b4 this code, but is not working. "Syntax Error(Missing operator) in query expression"

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

For example -

Table A | Username(PK)| Address|

Table B | ID | Phone | Username(FK)|

Table C | SN | Brand | Model | Username(FK)

```
rs = st.executeQuery

("SELECT * FROM (A Inner Join B on A.Username = B.Username) Inner Join C on A.Username = C.Username");
```

if anyone looking for inner join 3 tables together by Using JAVA and Link to Access
use the referenece above.

Make sure you must link the table relationship in Access before run the java program if not it will pop out "ERROR IN ROW"

Thanks everyone who helping me :)