# Joing the Tables to get the required data, I got three tables which are connected and i want to get the data from the 3rd table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, left-join, inner-join

My First Table Name is `UserClient` and it contains `UserTrainerID`. Using `UserTrainerID`, Second Table is `UserTrainer` and it contains `UserID` (I want to Know the `UserID` of `UserTrainer` using `UserTrainerID`), now third table is `User` where with the help of `userID` I want to get the `UserName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select a.username from t3 a,t2 b,t1 c 
    where a.userid=b.userid and b.UserTrainerID= c.UserTrainerID ;
```

Comment: It is preferable, now, to put the join conditions in the `ON` clause rather than in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is syntax to join three tables, I hope you will be able to join your tables accordingly:

```
SELECT t1.col, t3.col FROM table1 
             join table2 ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey
             join table3 ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-join-three-tables-in-sql-query-mysql-sqlserver.html#ixzz2zyYzv3pD

or [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)