# SQL 3 table join - Syntax

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to build up a view of related data.  The results will come from several tables, but I am trying to pull information from 3 tables at the moment - Once I have the syntax for this I'll be able to join the other tables.

Currently my statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID,
dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION.CLIENT_BOX_BARCODE,
dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION.WMS_BOX_BARCODE,
dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION.BOX_SIZE,
dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION.STORAGE_LOCATION, 
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.WELL_NAME_LEASE,
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.WELL, 
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.PROSPECT, 
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID,
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.COUNTY_PARISH_BOROUGH,
dict.DICT_PROVINCE_COUNTY.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID,
dict.DICT_PROVINCE_COUNTY.STATE_PROVINCE
FROM dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION as MCHI,     
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE, dict.DICT_PROVINCE_COUNTY 
INNER JOIN dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE AS CC
ON MCHI.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID = CC.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID
INNER JOIN dict.DICT_PROVINCE_COUNTY as DPC
ON DPC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID = CC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID
```

Running the above gives me 'could not be bound' errors.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I've used this answer here as reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables

Comment: Don't mix old style implicit joins (comma separated), and modern explicit JOIN syntax. Too confusing. (Stick to explicit JOIN, easier to write, easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.)

Comment: Please accept the anser of @blam

Comment: @KarmaEDV It is not my answer.  Only my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be wrong. You are given alias table name then it use. And your join wrong. try this

```
SELECT
MCHI.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID,
MCHI.CLIENT_BOX_BARCODE,
MCHI.WMS_BOX_BARCODE,
MCHI.BOX_SIZE,
MCHI.STORAGE_LOCATION, 
CC.WELL_NAME_LEASE,
CC.WELL, 
CC.PROSPECT, 
CC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID,
CC.COUNTY_PARISH_BOROUGH,
DPC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID,
DPC.STATE_PROVINCE
FROM dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION as MCHI     
INNER JOIN dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE AS CC
ON MCHI.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID = CC.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID
INNER JOIN dict.DICT_PROVINCE_COUNTY as DPC
ON DPC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID = CC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID
```

More detail to refer this link
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly.  I appreciate your response :)

Comment: I did vote you up, but it doesn't show my vote for the time being.   Regardless, I appreciate it - Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
MCHI.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID,
MCHI.CLIENT_BOX_BARCODE,
MCHI.WMS_BOX_BARCODE,
MCHI.BOX_SIZE,
MCHI.STORAGE_LOCATION, 
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.WELL_NAME_LEASE,
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.WELL, 
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.PROSPECT, 
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID,
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE.COUNTY_PARISH_BOROUGH,
DPC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID,
DPC.STATE_PROVINCE
FROM dbo.TB_MASTER_CONTAINER_HEADER_INFORMATION as MCHI,     
dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE, dict.DICT_PROVINCE_COUNTY 
INNER JOIN dbo.TB_CHEVRON_CORE AS CC
ON MCHI.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID = CC.UNIQUE_CONTAINER_ID
INNER JOIN dict.DICT_PROVINCE_COUNTY as DPC
ON DPC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID = CC.UNIQUE_PROVINCE_ID
```

Post full error for more help

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly.  I appreciate your response :)

Comment: But here you join with same tables twice, both old style comma separated syntax, then modern JOIN syntax.