# how to fire mysql query to get particular data?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
      quote,topics,name,topic_en 
FROM 
     `topic`,`author`,`quote` 
WHERE   
     topics like '%Age%' 
     and topic_en= 'Age'
     and quote.author_id=author.id
```

I have three tables:

- Topic
- Quote
- author
- topic table contains one field topic_en
- author table contains name of author and
- quote table contains quote and topics

I want the data from all these table. quote and topics from quote table,author name from author table and topic_en from topic table where topic_en is like topics of quote table and author id which is in quote table must be equal to id in author table. i have made above query which work partially not for all topic_en.
Any help to get out from this.....

Comment: Read MySQLi or PDO tutorials, running a query in PHP is well described there.

Comment: but how can i fulfill my requirement. I did try after that i came here

Comment: You need to do more research before you ask this kind of questions, do you know w3schools?

Comment: You need to search for inner joins. Read this, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
      quote,topics,name,topic_en 
FROM 
     `author`
INNER JOIN `quote` ON quote.author_id=author.id
INNER JOIN `topic` ON topic.??? = ???.???
WHERE   
     topics LIKE '%Age%' 
     AND topic_en= 'Age'
```

Replace the `???` with appropriate field in table `topic` and a field in either `author` or `quote`, to join the table `topic` with that table.

Does that help?