# (My)SQL: Join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm new to (My)SQL and need some help: 
In a database I have 3 tables, an example:

purchases:

```
id model price
------------
1   1  2500
2   2  14000
```

manufacturer:

```
id  name
-----------
1   Opel
2   Crysler
```

model:

```
id  name    manufacturer  
-------------------------
1   Astra       1
2   C 300       2
```

In the table purchases **model** is a foreign key and is **linked to model.id**. In model **manufacturer** is a foreign key and is **linked to manufacturer.id**.

My aim is a table which looks like below:

```
id model   price  manufacturer
------------------------------
1   Astra  2500   Opel
2   C300   14000  Chrysler
```

I know how to do a JOIN in the table purchases to get the model's name. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the manufacturer?

My SQL-query:

```
SELECT * FROM purchases
JOIN model
ON purchases.model = model.id
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the query that you do know how to write.  As a hint:  the ultimate query is just one more `JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited my question. My approach would be something like (for the second JOIN): `JOIN manufacturer ON purchases.name = manufacturer.id` , however for SQL purchaes.name is an unknown clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with 'inner join':

```
select m.name as model, p.price, mf.name as manufacturer
from purchases p 
inner join
model m on p.model = m.id 
inner join
manufacturer mf on m.manufacturer = mf.id;
```

You can join your tables with 'where'.

Try it:

```
 select m.name as model, p.price, mf.name as manufacturer
 from purchases p, manufacturer mf, model m
 where m.manufacturer = mf.id
 and p.model = m.id
```

But with the "where" is not very good, and considered a archaic way.

There is a question similar with your, perhaps might help you to clarify the question:
[SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel 
I do not forgot this condition. Please review the text .

Comment: Sorry, i've allready deleted my comment, before you posted yours. However i probably wouldn't oversee that condition, if you would use `JOIN .. ON ..`.

Comment: I'm not downvoting the answer, but the upvote is totally inappropriate.  Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.  This is an archaic syntax that has been replaced by the more powerful `JOIN` and `ON` keywords -- for many, many years.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my answer. Thank you for your Collaboration

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to join tables is using the `JOIN` (and related) keywords.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
 select m.name as model, p.price, mf.name as manufacturer
 from purchases p JOIN
      model m
      on p.model = m.id
      manufacturer mf
      on m.manufacturer = mf.id;
```

Comment: Your comment doesn't relate to the question, because the OP is already using the JOIN syntax. BTW: the second JOIN keyword is missing.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . The original version of the question did not have a sample query.  And, the other answer was only using commas when I write this.