# Join three tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables.

**A**

```
ID   NAME  
---  ----   
1    abc   
2    asd  
3    qwe
```

**B**

```
ID    INCOME  
---   ------  
1      2  
2      3  
1      4
```

**C**

```
NAME   TOTAL  
----  ----    
abc    8  
asd    20
```

I want to join this three tables with a SQL query to produce an output like

```
ID INCOME TOTAL  
---------------
1    6       8  
2    3      20
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select 
    t1.id, sum(t2.income) income, sum(t3.total) total
from 
    table1 t1 
join 
    table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
join 
    table3 t3 on t3.name = t1.name
group by 
    t1.id
order by 
    t1.id
```