# relate tables to make a list (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with different columns except for one called "FileKey". I need a query that returns that field of the 3 tables as a list [I think here is more easy to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hojw.png)

Please be patient, i'm new here :(

Comment: HINT `UNION` ....

Comment: Is there no other way? elsewhere I must do the same but with more tables, I don't want a query so big

Comment: where are you building this query? it is directly in the database? or you will call this query from a  programing language like C# or Java or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best possible way to do this is by using UNION Operator.**
but if you don't want to use the UNION what you can do is to insert your all three table data to a temporary table and later on view it using a Select Statement.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ID INT);
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (ID INT);
DECLARE @TableC TABLE (ID INT);
DECLARE @Needed TABLE (ID INT);

INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES(53)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES(49)
INSERT INTO @TableC VALUES(34)

INSERT INTO @Needed (Id)
SELECT ID FROM @TableA

INSERT INTO @Needed (Id)
SELECT ID FROM @TableB

INSERT INTO @Needed (Id)
SELECT ID FROM @TableC


SELECT * FROM @Needed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple JOIN of the three tables ON the FileKey value.

[SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

Comment: No, because there is no matching value between the columns to use "On".  @bstiffler582

Comment: @Haydee if the FileKey value is unique for all three tables then you will have to use UNION.

Answer (score 0):

you can use union like this:

```
Select FieldKey from TableA 
union 
Select FieldKey from TableB 
union
Select FieldKey from TableC
```

Using union it will not duplicate data if you have the same FieldKey in diferents tables.

if you want to duplicate data use union all like this:

```
Select FieldKey from TableA 
union all
Select FieldKey from TableB 
union all
Select FieldKey from TableC
```

check this link below to understand it better
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp