# Calculating which activity each person is assigned to

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem in which I need to be able to count the number of activities a child has registered to do. At the moment I have this:

```
SELECT child_fname, activity_id
FROM Child
LEFT JOIN Activity
ON Activity.ActivityID=activity.activity_id
ORDER BY Child.child_fname;
```

and my tables are like this:

Child Table

- child_firstname
- child_secondname
- child_age

Activity

- activity_id
- activity_name
- activity_price

ChildActivity

- child_id
- activity_id

---

I'm looking for something like this

- [Name][Number of Activities]
- Sam Smith 5
- Rachel Smith 4

I tried using an JOIN but my query doesn't update for new data

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the last sentence? Why does the given `JOIN` query not "update for new data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you want

```
SELECT child_fname as Name, count(activity_id) as `Number of Activities`
FROM Child
LEFT JOIN ChildActivity
ON ChildActivity.child_id=Child.child_id
GROUP BY Child.child_id
ORDER BY COUNT(activity_id) DESC;
```

The point is that you want to join `Child` with `ChildActivity` and group by `Child`, so that, for each record in `Child` you get a count of activities.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, yes, I do have a child_id which is a primary field in the Child table

Comment: Yep this works! Do you know how to sort it by the person with the highest number of activities? I tried adding this

GROUP BY ChildActivity.activity_id;

But it added them all together (the children) as some have the same first name

Comment: I've edited the query to include the order by clause

Comment: Thank you Chris Lear! This works to perfection, I think I correctly marked your answer as the one. Thank you so much again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT Child.child_firstname, COUNT(Activity.activity_id)
FROM Child
INNER JOIN Activity ON Activity.activity_id=ChildActivity.activity_id
INNER JOIN ChildActivity ON ChildActivity.child_id=Child.child_id
ORDER BY Child.child_firstname;
```

*Ps: check column names and tables, please.*
**Example** [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)