# Reference table name column in another table in join - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, dynamic

I have following condition :

Table-1 
col1   col2    col3
1         40     100 (identity column value for tblABC)
2         41     101 (identity column value for tblDEF)

Table-2 
col1       col2        col3
40        tblABC     tblABCPrimaryKey
41        tblDEF     tblDEFPrimaryKey

========= Different tables ==============
tblABC 
tblPrimaryKeyId    col2
100                        VALUE

tblDEF
tblPrimaryKeyId    col2
101                       VALUE

I need to get below column in join 
         select Table-1.col1, 
                   Table-2.col2, 
                   [ tblABC.col2 OR tblDEF.col2 and so on depending on the table]
from Table-1 
INNER JOIN (join goes here)

I want to get
col1 from Table-1,
col2 from Table-2 where col2 of Table-1 matches col1 of Table-2,
col2 from (TABLES IN COL2 of Table-2 where col3 of Table-2 matches column in those tables in col-2 [Different tables])

Please help.

Comment: can you post that as formatted text instead of all the HTML tags and explain what your end result should be?

Comment: Hi, I do not know how to format the text. You can find the attchement image for what am I looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and, regarding posting pictures, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584

Comment: I haven't understand clearly what you are asking, but this might help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Please find the edited text if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT Table1.col1
    , Table2.col2,
    , COALESCE(';

SELECT
    @sql = @sql + #Table2.col2 + '.col2, '
FROM #Table2;

SET @sql = @sql + ' NULL)
INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.col2 = Table2.col1';

SELECT
    @sql = @sql + '
LEFT JOIN ' + col2 + ' 
    ON Table2.col2 = ''' + col2 + ''' 
    AND Table1.col3 = ' + col2 + '.col1'
FROM #Table2

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but tblABC,tblDEF are dynamic, I do not know how many table names are there in col2 of Table-2. I need to get the data from all those table.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make the joins dynamic based on what's in Table2. You may need to add a `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate joins?

Comment: Okay. Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried your approach, I had to do some tweaks but I got the direction, thanks for your help.

Comment: Gald to help. Please accept the answer if you thinks it's about right.