# how to get datatable if textbox matches your data in database

Tags: vb.net

how can I possibly populate my table if like textbox.text matches from my data inside database.
I'm stuck here, not sure where I did go wrong

```
 Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim dbcommand As String
    dbcommand = "SELECT * FROM aws_rdp where csn_user like " & txtCSNUser.Text & ""
    adt = New OleDbDataAdapter(dbcommand, dbconn)
    datatable = New DataTable
    adt.Fill(datatable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = datatable
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is it that people think that it's a good idea to ask questions about SQL code without showing the SQL code? VB code that constructs SQL code is not SQL code. Regardless, any basic reading on the the [SQL `LIKE` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp) will tell you what is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: Also, you should learn how to use parameters in your queries. The way you're doing it is a great way to allow a malicious user to delete your entire database.

Comment: So what’s the problem?  Are you not getting the expected results back or maybe an error?

Comment: OK, there's more going on there than I first thought, which makes it even worse that you have provided all the relevant information and probably not even looked at your own SQL code.

Comment: You need to use an [OleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.selectcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) with the `OleDbDataAdapter`. See the linked documentation for how to add an SQL parameter to the `SelectCommand` to pass the value of `txtCSNUser.Text`.

Comment: ![This is what I wanted to do and I'm still new on this programming][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMav1.png

Comment: @NnekLecxe 1) It appears to me that you want `=` instead of `LIKE`. 2) You will need to *join* the tables: [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10195451/1115360). 3) Make sure to use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) so that all the variable types match up.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ' before and after the quotation marks surrounding the textbox text. If you're trying to find that text within the text stored in the database you will also need wildcards (%) surrounding it too. Try:

```
dbcommand = "SELECT * FROM aws_rdp where csn_user like '%" & txtCSNUser.Text & "%'"
```

Also, as others have stated, look into using parameters in your SQL code as it will help prevent things like SQL injection and is always good practice

Comment: Tried this code, but still no luck with it. Anyways, heres what I really wanted
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMav1.png

Comment: If you don't mind, how does that parameters work or so? How can I look at it? Sorry, amateur coder here

Comment: Put a placeholder in your SQL statement where the value would be, like this:
dbcommand = "SELECT * FROM aws_rdp where csn_user like ?"
Then insert the parameter using:
command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("csn_user", txtCSNUser.Text))

I'm not too familiar with OleDB so if that doesn't work check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem by using this code. Anyways, thanks for your time replying on my query, will surely take note of your advises for my future references

```
 Dim dbcommand As String = "SELECT * FROM aws_rdp where csn_user like '%" & txtCSNUser.Text & "%'"
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(dbcommand, dbconn)
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
    Dim datatable As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(datatable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = datatable

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "IP Address"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Username"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Password"
```