# Need to return only first row of one table in a group

Tags: sql, database

I have a sql Query Like this

```
Select a.column1,b.column2,c.column3 
from table1 a,table2 b, table3 c
where a.customerName = 'Michael' 
and a.id= b.id 
and a.id = c.id 
and b.id = c.id
```

My problem is table 1 and table 2 have only one row satisfying this condition always so there is no issues but table3 column 3 contains two rows so duplication fo rows happen just to display the two values of table3. How can I return only one row of c.column3 from table3 irrespective of how many rows it has?

I tried using

```
Select a.column1,b.column2,c.(TOP 1 column3) 
from table1 a,table2 b, table3 c
where a.customerName = 'Michael' 
and a.id= b.id 
and a.id = c.id 
and b.id = c.id
```

but still it did not work. Is there a way to achieve this? I am using SQL database.

Example :

> select a.Full_Name FROM table1 a WHERE a.ID LIKE
> '%1002%'

this gives

Full_Name
Arun
TestName

But when I do

> select a.FullName,b.work FROM table1 a,
> table2 b WHERE a.ID = b.id AND a.ID LIKE
> '%1002%'

This gives since work column for the ID 1002 has two rows (one row containing 2 and another row containing 1)

Full_Name                 work
Arun                        2
Arun                        2
TestName                    1
TestName                    1

My expected output is instead of returning both the rows I would like it(work column) to return only one row. how is this achieved?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output?

Comment: You would like to return any row of table3?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: _First_? As in alphabetically first?

Comment: Tip 2: Chose table aliases that make sense. a, b, c etc are poor table aliases. t1, t2 and t3 are much better (if your tables are named table1, table2 and table3.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the inner join one way or another to get only matching rows. This might help you to build the inner join: [inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

However, if you indeed get multiple correctly matched rows and want to get only the first one, use `limit 1;` at the end of your query.

Comment: Note that LIMIT is a product specific functionality, and OP is using TOP - specific for another dbms.

Comment: Also, LIMIT is not the solution here. OP probably needs GROUP BY.

Comment: Would be easier if there were exact names of tables and the context in the original question.

Comment: I'd also like to see sample table data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want any `column3` of `table3` then use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`

```
Select a.column1,
   b.column2,
   max(c.column3)
from table1 a,table2 b, table3 c
where a.customerName = 'Michael' 
and a.id= b.id 
and a.id = c.id 
and b.id = c.id
group by a.column1,b.column2
```

However, if there are more different values of `c.column3` for each pair `(a.column1, b.column2)` then there is probably some rule which would select `c.column3`. My SQL simply selects the highest `c.column3` value in such case.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

If you need lost of columns, then use `row_number()`:

```
select a.column1,b.column2,c.column3 
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on a.id = b.id join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by c.id order by c.id) as seqnum
      from table3 c
     ) c
     on a.id = c.id and c.seqnum = 1;
where a.customerName = 'Michael'
```

Note that the condition `b.id = c.id` is redundant.  The other two conditions imply that this is always true.