# SQL for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

*Account*

```
acc_id
acc_name
acc_status
acc_owner_id
```

*User*

```
role_id
user_name
```

*Sub_Contract_ID*

```
basic_con_id
start_date
end_date
```

also,

```
Account.acc_owner_id = User.role_id
```

I want the result to contain

```
acc_id
acc_name
acc_status
user_name
basic_con_id
start_date
end_date
WHERE acc_status  = "Inactive"
```

I did try a way but was getting stuck at how I can pull `user_name` using `Account.acc_owner_id = User.role_id` and fit it into the main query

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
Account.acc_id,
Account.acc_name,
Account. acc_status,
Sub_Contract_ID.basic_con_id,
Sub_Contract_ID.basic_con_id.start_date,
Sub_Contract_ID.end_date
FROM 
(
Account,
User,
Sub_Contract_ID)
WHERE Account. acc_status = “Inactive”
```

Please advise!

Comment: How is sub_contract_id related in this

Comment: There's several problems here. Firstly you put your delimited list of tables in parenthesis (`()`); the `FROM` doesn't go inside parenthesis (it's not a function). Speaking of the delimited list of tables, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN has been around for **30 years**; long past time you adopted it. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Also you're using "smart quotes" around `Inactive` which aren't supported. Also is `Inactive` *meant* to be the **column** `Inactive`or should it be the literal string `'Inactive'`?

Comment: `USER` is also a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in T-SQL. If you want to reference an object with a reserved keyword you *must* delimit identify it. Ideally, however, don't use reserved keywords for object names at all (or any name that needs delimited identification).

Comment: JOINs are a fundamental feature of SQL. Not knowing how they work is like asking someone how to parallel park a car, but saying you don't know how the steering wheel works. As Stackoverflow is not geared up to teach the fundamentals of a language, I strongly recommend, for your own benefit, that you invest time in a course for SQL. There are a great many free courses online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.acc_id, a.acc_name, a.acc_status, u.user_name, sci.basic_con_id, sci.start_date, sci.end_date
FROM Account AS a
LEFT JOIN User AS u ON a.acc_owner_id = u.role_id
LEFT JOIN Sub_Contract_ID AS sci ON ????
WHERE a.acc_status = 'Inactive'
```

You just have to replace ???? by the relation between User or Account and Sub_Contract_ID because you haven't describe this relation in your post.

Comment: Thanks for this, I do not have any relation in `Sub_Contract_ID`. I have to get all the field from `Account` table and `user_name` from `User` table where  `acc_owner_id` =`role_id` and where `acc_status` is "Inactive". Now for this set of accounts I want all the fields of `Sub_Contract_ID`. How can I do this

Comment: If you don't have any relation between Sub_Contract_Id and other tables, it quite impossible to join.
I don't undertand what you want to do.

Answer (score -3):

use JOIN to connect several tables

```
SELECT *
FROM Account 
JOIN "User" on Account.acc_owner_id = User.role_id
WHERE Account. acc_status = 'Inactive'
```

please note:
There are different types of joins, and the syntax is DB-system specific. In case you are using a DB-system where "User" is a keyword like in MS-SQL, you have to escape it according to the DB-system specifications, in case of MS-SQL you have to use double quotes.

Comment: The above still has multiple other issues. The ANSI-89 JOIN syntax was just *one* problem.

Comment: the main question was how to apply Account.acc_owner_id = User.role_id

Comment: And the above would error, @Draz .

Comment: ok, one point for this if you run it in MS sql (however, it really depends for the db system you are using)